# Unanswered question list in Collectives shows merged questions

Tags: bug, status-planned, collectives, merged-questions

This is a bit of an edge case, but it does need some noting, as this is potentially confusing to users.

There was a flag on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606588/how-to-attach-and-show-image-in-mail-using-php) that read

> This is the top unanswered question in the PHP Collective. I don't get why it hasn't been closed and is currently in a state that can't be answered.

I poked around for a bit and, sure enough, I was able to see what this user saw ([link to view](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php?tab=questions&subtab=hot&postFilter=SubCommunityQuestionPageFilter#sort-select))

[image: Trending sort]

This is an unusual state. Normally a merge is done after a duplicate closure, but the system doesn't require a closure before a merge. A merged question, however, cannot be answered any more than a closed one can. While we could fix it by closing the question, this view should not include unclosed merged questions in a list of questions to potentially answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out, we have filed a bug to fix this. Likely it won't be handled until we come back around to these lists in Collectives (there are a few things like this that we'd like to change/fix).